# for loop in multi generic lists best practice in C#

Tags: c#, generics, for-loop

Since we knew using multi nested loop is not good thing does it there any way better than using it, what I want to do is as the following 
`hhScreenControls` is a generic list of Type `MiControl` and each item has different type of `MiControl` class and if the current Item is `typeOf MiTab` it contains children so I want to compare the children and remove them from Components List 
..

```
foreach (var control in hhScreenControls)
{
   var tab = control as MiTab;
   if (tab != null)
   {
       foreach (var tabControl in hhScreenControls)
       {
           if (tab.FindControl(tabControl) != null)
           {
               HHScreenComponent tabControlComnpare = new HHScreenComponent();
               tabControlComnpare.Name = control.Name;
               for (int i = 0; i < Components.Count; i++)
               {
                   if (Components[i].Name == tabControlComnpare.Name)
                       Components.Remove(Components[i]);
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

if I missed to explain anything tell me

Comment: Whats the second loop for? You're already iterating over the controls?..

Comment: You might want to use a decreasing loop, as you may find items move as you remove them, so if you remove item 0, item 1 may become item 0...

Comment: since the control is type of MiTab so I want to iterating over the controls again to check them and find tabControls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, nested loops are not *bad* - sometimes they are necessary. In your case you may be able to simplify stuff:

The second loop doesn't have to go over all the controls, but since you already know that you want the controls that are on `tab`, you only need to loop over the controls on each tab page:

```
foreach (var tab in hhScreenControls.OfType<MiTab>())
{
    foreach (var tabPage in tab.Pages)
    {
        foreach (var tabControl in tabPage.Controls)
        {
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case I can't get the controls of the tab easily cause the MiTab contains Tab Pages then I can get the controls of the tabs

Comment: Well, you can iterate over the tab pages of the `MiTab` as an intermediate step. I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to note that doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Components.Count; i++)
{
   if (Components[i].Name == tabControlComnpare.Name)
      Components.Remove(Components[i]);
}
```

Is a bad idea because you are removing your item as you move your index. You should do it the reverse way.

```
for (int i = Components.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (Components[i].Name == tabControlComnpare.Name)
      Components.Remove(Components[i]);
}
```

---

The first way will make you miss some of your items, but the second way will not:

Example, suppose you have:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

And to put it really simple, suppose you want to remove every item without `if` qualification, this is what happen when you remove item as your index moves forward:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

[b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1 - a is removed!
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

[b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 2
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[c, d, e, f] #cycle 2 - c is removed
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[c, d, e, f] #cycle 3
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[c, d, f] #cycle 3 - e is removed
       ^  <-- here is the indexer
```

Note that you might miss some items. The idea above is retained even you remove item with `if` condition. But if you do it the reverse way, this is what happen:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f] #cycle 1
                ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e] #cycle 1 - f is removed
                ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d, e] #cycle 2
             ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d] #cycle 2 - e is removed
             ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c, d] #cycle 3
          ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c] #cycle 3 - d is removed
          ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b, c] #cycle 4
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b] #cycle 4 - c is removed
       ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a, b] #cycle 5
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a] #cycle 5 - b is removed
    ^  <-- here is the indexer

[a] #cycle 6
 ^  <-- here is the indexer

[] #cycle 6 - a is removed
 ^  <-- here is the indexer
```

Thus you really go through every item in your iteration.